# Speed up "is in" for DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

Given a DataFrame, I would like to add a row if its not in the DF already.

```
if state not in df.index:
    # append new state DataFrame
    df = df.append(pd.Series([0] * len(self.actions), index=df.columns, name=state))
```

`state` is a string like this `[0 1 12 36 67 0 14 5 6 4]` (a list of 10 entries, handed over as a string).

For the first few rows added, this takes about 0.0045 seconds on average. Having 10.000+ rows already makes it significantly slower, about 0.0623 seconds, and with 100.000+ rows it becomes something like 0.1364 seconds...

Is there any way to speed up the check if the index already exists? I am new to python, but maybe there is a way to keep the index in the RAM and check there for better performance? Maybe hashing the index would speed it up, or maybe a combination of those?

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why not create a `DataFrame`, concatenate them and drop duplicates?

Comment: I find 0.1364 not too slow, certainly not for 100K+ rows. Perhaps that depends on how often you're running this in e.g. a loop, but in that case, finding another way to code this may be the more appropriate solution.

Comment: Well, it runs in a loop and gets called 10+ times a second, and since this is not the only thing happening it is the bottleneck of the code. I understand that this is not too bad, but as a noob it seems to be a very inefficient way to check like that

Comment: Is your index sorted? This have good pick up in searching. But @gmds is probably the best idea, if you can wait to the end to drop duplicates.